# Complexidade algoritmica de map

Tags: python, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Poderiam me dizer qual a complexidade algoritmica deste código, em especial, qual a complexidade da função `map`

```
numero = map(lambda x: x[0], lista)
map(lambda x: (numero.count(x)), sorted(set(numero)))
```

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @LuizVieira, url muito cool!

Comment: Sendo `map` uma função de ordem superior, esta análise pode complicar-se. Eu esperaria algo como  `map (f,   lista)` tender a ser `O(n X)` sendo ` X` a complexidade de `f`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Map é uma parte da programação funcional que é possível se fazer em Python. Nele nós podemos aplicar o algoritmo de regressão em menor espaço de código.

Neste caso, na sua primeira linha, o primeiro map pega o indice 0 da variável lista:

> numero = map(lambda x: x[0], lista)

Na segunda linha do seu código, você está replicando a função contida na variável numero e contando o número de vezes que ocorre o item lista[0], só que o segundo map está sendo aplicado no valor: sorted(set(numero))

> map(lambda x: (numero.count(x)), sorted(set(numero)))

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente um `map` é O(n) pois internamente ele itera sobre a lista, uma operação linear, e também cria uma nova lista de mesmo tamanho para receber as transformações, também uma operação linear, assim temos O(n * 2) que em big O é considerado O(n). Contudo como dito no comentário do @JJoao a complexidade final vai variar conforme a função que realiza a transformação da lista (as `lambdas` no caso do seu código), então por exemplo se a função/lambda utilizada realizar uma operação constante a complexidade permaneceria O(n).

Quanto as duas linhas:

1. A primeira é O(n) pois é feito um `map` sobre `lista`, uma operação O(n)), e a lambda realiza apenas a operação constante `x[0]`;
2. A segunda é razoávelmente mais complicada de se avaliar. Começamos observando que `sorted(set(numero)))` possui complexidade O(n + (n log n)) (n para a operação `set` e "n log n" para a operação `sorted`), contudo "n log n" predomina sobre "n" então consideramos as duas operações apenas como O(n log n). Agora o interessante é que pegamos essa lista gerada por `sorted(set(numero))` e alimentamos o `map` com ela, sendo que para cada elemento dessa lista será realizada a operação `numero.count(x)`. Para essa parte vamos dizer que a lista gerada por `sorted(set(numero)))` possui tamanho `z` e que a lista `numero` possui tamanho `w`, assim podemos dizer o `map` realiza `z` vezes a operação `numero.count`, então acabamos com a complexidade O(z * w + (n log n)), onde z * w domina sendo então na realidade `O(z * w)`, ufa!